# Meteor error in trying to use collections

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am currently pulling data from collections in the MongoDB but there are 2 in particular that will not work either giving me the following error:

> Exception from sub Assets id i574gxNDc9RdHERNn TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of undefined

Or:

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'attachSchema' of undefined

Or:

> Object # has no method 'attachSchema'

depending on how I configure it. Does anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong. I am using the same code for the ones that work as well as the ones that are throwing errors.

The collection looks like this:

```
Assets = Collections.Assets = Meteor.Assets;
```

Querying in server/publish.js:

```
  Meteor.publish("Assets", function (){ 
    return Meteor.Assets.find({});
  });
```

Changing it to:

```
new Mongo.Collection('Assets');
```

Gives error:

> Exception from sub Assets id ZgzZyNYPmMr5gtFGn TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of undefined

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show us _how_ you query your collection ?

Comment: Where are you calling `attachSchema`? Also, no method `find` means that `Meteor.Assets` does not have `find` on it. I'm very confused on why you're creating a collection like you are doing. Why don't you create them like this? http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection

Comment: I'm calling `attachSchema` in the same js file as the collection is created. I am using the collection that way because those collections are already created in the database and I was worried that using that would overwrite the data currently in there. Or does using that automatically pull the data when everything starts up?

Comment: Meteor won't overwrite the data in your existing collection so you should just define your collection normally. `Assets = new Mongo.Collection('Assets')` assuming that in mongo you have `db.Assets`

Comment: Ok, after I change it to that I still have the problem that it has no find method.

Answer (score 0):

Running the following from the command line in the top (root) directory of the project might fix this (it helped me):

> **meteor add aldeed:collection2**